# TFS/C#: Logging a custom warning during the build process

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am hacking around a problem we've created for ourselves. What I would like to do is log a warning in our TFS builds for any code that is instantiating a specific class. I don't want a run time warning (I've got one in place already), I want a build time warning that ProjectX is using BadClass.cs. The idea being it will give us an additional place to see things that need to be fixed once our hack is no longer needed.

So something like this:

```
public class BadClass
{}
public class OkClass
{}

public class MyBadService
{
   var a = new BadClass(); <-- Logs a warning to the build output
}

public class MyOkService
{
   var a = new OkClass(); <-- Does not log a warning
}
```

Edit:
I do not like the idea of using Obsolete; its a misnomer. We've already got code with Obsolete attributes and this would get lost in the noise. I don't want a generic warning that I can't control the message for. I want bright neon signs with klaxons firing and a thousand exclamation points in the message. Basically everything I can do short of failing the build. I'm using the #warning precompiler directive right now and its mostly doing what I want but it requires a human to remember to add the warning. I'm looking for something more automagic. I've seen third party libraries do stuff like this so I know its possible.

Comment: Mark the class with `[Obsolete]`

Comment: Hi Lane, any update for this issue? If Johnson's answer is helpful to resolve this issue you can consider marking it as answer. And if you've found the solution, you can add it as answer to benefit other members. Just a reminder:)

Comment: See my edit. Thanks for following up Lance.

Comment: You're welcome. If there's any update, feel free to share it here:)

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be negative I think.

It seems that you use or call msbuild.exe to build your C# projects. But as far as I know, MSBuild in fact calls csc.exe to build C# projects in **build time**.

So actually what you want is logging a warning when the compiler compile the C# code if it recognize somewhere in your code uses the BadClass in **build time**.

If you have the source code of `BadClass` in the same solution, add a project reference format to the xx.csproj which contains `BadClass`, and set a #`warning` in the `BadClass` it may generate the warning in build time.

But I think the scenario you're in is something like: You developed one Assembly and distribute it to your user, so you want it generates a warning when the user calls one BadClass in your assembly and builds his own project to remind him of taking care when using this bad class. If so, this is impossible for msbuild AFAIK. If I misunderstand anything, feel free to know me know :)

**Update**:

As Daniel and Johnson said, [ObsoleteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=netframework-4.8) is enough to do this. Though no valid way to generate warnings from msbuild aspect directly, but msbuild will call C# compiler during build process, so generates a compiler warning can output to build output window.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Obsolete attribute? It can generate a build warning for you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=netframework-4.8
You can even make it emit an error too if you want.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid Obsolete. I'm not so sure I'd go with the "perfect answer" but if its the only practical answer then...

Comment: @LaneGoolsby AFAIK, to display warning to build output during building process, it needs generate a compiler warning or msbuild warning. But msbuild itself won't check the content of your code and check if you used some unique class. So you have to make a compiler warning which check the code when compiling. For this, `obsolete` can be practical and convenient.

Comment: @LaneGoolsby, don't get caught up with re-inventing the wheel. The language has already done it for you. It's there for a reason, to be used.